# nodemailer, req.body issues

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

relevant libs in use...

```
var bodyParser              = require('body-parser'),
    nodemailer              = require('nodemailer'),
    xoauth2                 = require('xoauth2');
```

rout...

```
router.post('/users/contact', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('../views/users/contact', {
  title: 'Contact',
  layout: 'userLayout.hbs',
  username: req.user.username,
  subject: req.body.subject,
  content: req.body.content
  });
});
```

my transporter options cfg...

```
var options = {
    from: 'asd',
    to: req.user.mail,    <<--------- works fine under mongodb pulling from db...
                                    |-------- 
    subject: req.body.subject, <<__/     those 2 params aren't working.
    text: req.body.content     <<  \     i believe transporter isn't the problem.
                                    |    if i set regular transporter param strings
                                    |    it works fine...
};                                  |--------
```

i need to know how to show **req.body** vars on a modal for example...
a contact modal which the user requested to enter subject and content.
means 1 input for subject and 1 textarea for content.
so my current **req.body.subject** and content returning an **EMPTY** field.
thx for ur time. :]

Comment: If the issue you are asking about is why `req.body.subject` does not have a valid value, then we need to see more of the relevant code.  `req.body.subject` will only have a value if you are handling a POST request and if you have the `body-parser` middleware properly installed.  If the issue you are asking about is purely a nodemailer issue and you do have valid values in your `options` structure, then show the code that uses nodemailer so people can see how you're calling it and how it is configured.

Answer (score 0):

relevant libs in use...

```
var bodyParser              = require('body-parser'),
    nodemailer              = require('nodemailer'),
    xoauth2                 = require('xoauth2');
```

rout...

```
router.post('/users/contact', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('../views/users/contact', {
  title: 'Contact',
  layout: 'userLayout.hbs',
  username: req.user.username,
  subject: req.body.subject,
  content: req.body.content
  });
});
```

my transporter options cfg...

```
var options = {
    from: 'asd',
    to: req.user.mail,    <<--------- works fine under mongodb pulling from db...
                                    |-------- 
    subject: req.body.subject, <<__/     those 2 params aren't working.
    text: req.body.content     <<  \     i believe transporter isn't the problem.
                                    |    if i set regular transporter param strings
                                    |    it works fine...
};                                  |--------
```

i need to know how to show **req.body** vars on a modal for example...
a contact modal which the user requested to enter subject and content.
means 1 input for subject and 1 textarea for content.
so my current **req.body.subject** and content returning an **EMPTY** field.
thx for ur time. :]